# clang-format indentation of class fields and methods, opening curly braces for functions and enums

Tags: c++, clang-format

My clang-format produces code like this:

```
enum class SomeEnum{ VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 };

class SomeClass {
    public:
    void someMethod();

    private:
    int m_field;
};

void someFunc() 
{
    // ...
}
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
enum class SomeEnum {
    VAL1,
    VAL2,
    VAL3
};

class SomeClass {
    public:
        void someMethod();

    private:
        int m_field;
};

void someFunc() {
    // ...
}
```

So I need enums to not be reduced to one line like this, for class methods and fields to have an additional level of indentation after access specifiers, and for the opening curly brace of my functions to be one space after ')' and not in another line

Here is my .clang-format file

```yaml
AccessModifierOffset: '0'
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'true'
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignTrailingComments: 'true'
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: 'false'
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: 'true'
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: 'true'
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: 'true'
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: 'false'
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: 'Yes'
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
ColumnLimit: '120'
CompactNamespaces: 'false'
Cpp11BracedListStyle: 'true'
DerivePointerAlignment: 'true'
FixNamespaceComments: 'true'
IndentCaseLabels: 'true'
IndentWidth: '4'
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: 'false'
Language: Cpp
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: '2'
NamespaceIndentation: All
SortIncludes: 'true'
SortUsingDeclarations: 'true'
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: 'false'
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: 'false'
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: 'false'
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: 'true'
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: 'true'
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: 'true'
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: 'true'
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInAngles: 'false'
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInSquareBrackets: 'false'
TabWidth: '4'
UseTab: ForContinuationAndIndentation
```

Comment: Why do you force boolean values and numbers to be strings?

Comment: @273K it was auto generated by [this](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) online tool I was trying out. I removed all the ' characters as soon as I found out they were not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false # is available since clang-format 12.
IndentAccessModifiers: true         # is available since clang-format 13.
BraceWrapping:
  AfterFunction: false
```